# Append component to body in onClick function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to append a Modal component to the doc body on click of a trigger, but I think my syntax is wrong...

```
openModal() {
    console.log(this.state.isModalOpen);
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    $('body').append(
    <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim">
      <NewAlbum onClick={this.closeModal}/>
    </Modal>
    )
  }
<button onClick={this.openModal}>Trigger</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you have missed a few of the React fundamentals.  You need to let React take care of your rendering for you.  This is the typical usage for what you are after:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isModalOpen: false }; 
    this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
  }

  toggleModal() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Trigger</button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} transitionName="modal-anim">
          <NewAlbum onClick={this.toggleModal}/>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }      
}
```

I would highly recommend you go through the react documentation and get some of the foundations cemented: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know I have major deficits and trying to learn on the fly.

Comment: I'm getting an unexpected token erro on toggleModal = () => ... is that supposed to be just toggleModal() {...}

Comment: Ok, you probably aren't running babel in stage 1.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: What preset are you using?